# Power shell health check up in sharepoint 2013

Tags: powershell

How to test the health check up for all the  site collection under the webappplication in sharepoint 2013 using Powershell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your powershell command box. .

```
    $siteUrl = Read-Host "Enter Site URL"
    $rootSite = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($siteUrl)
    $spWebApp = $rootSite.WebApplication

    foreach($site in $spWebApp.Sites)
    {    
      Test-SPSite -Identity $site.Url
      Write-Host "Completed" 
    }
```